# Agile related question to our personal life

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask few questions related to applying agile, scrum and kanban in specific in our personal and family life.

**Here is what I have in mind:**

> After taking course about agile and scrum philosophy, I found it very interested to apply the same concepts on personal and family life. After searching for it, I found blog on ["Becoming an Agile Family"](http://scrumfamily.wordpress.com/) using scrum and using [Personal Kanban](http://www.personalkanban.com/pk/). I would like to ask if someone had successfully used scrum to manage personal tasks and to plan for better family relationships and how he/she adjusted agile, scrum and kanban concepts to such thing.

Do you think this kind of questions should be asked on PM-SE or somewhere else?

Comment: Related to personal life? Hmmm, that sounds a bit iffy, could you post an example in the body of the question for context? It would be unfair to shoot down the idea or say it's all good without at least seeing an example. :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you're looking for our [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 0):

I think a question about using Scrum and Kanban to manage family or personal projects *could* be on-topic; however, as it stands the example is a "getting to know you" polling question.

Simply asking people to raise their hands and say "yes, I've done this" is the type of question we try to avoid because it could theoretically attract tens or hundreds of competing answers. Theoretically... this won't happen here because we're a smaller site, but the result is still the same:  Having people say "sure, I did that" won't give you a definitive idea of what the best answer is.

**Here are some tips on how you could expand on this idea:**

- Focus on a problem you're facing using Scrum or Kanban to manage a personal or family project. Real problems, real questions, have answers that can be extremely helpful, not just to you but also to future visitors.
- You *could* ask a theory question, but make sure you're focusing on something that will get answers, not just a list of people who have tried this.

Finally, I can't promise this would be on-topic, but at this stage in our growth, I encourage us to try new things and see how it goes in terms of community acceptance. To make sure it's accepted, make sure there's a project management aspect to the question.

If it doesn't work, we can edit the post and see if it would work on the [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) site, as Aarthi suggests.

As an aside, if you want to *discuss* the topic, as opposed to asking a definitive question, I encourage you to try and entice people into our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Chat works great for discussions or getting a feel for who might have tried something. :)